# Sails - Waterline: Where can I find a complete list of model attributes properties?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am currently looking for a complete list with description of the available properties for Sails models' attributes.

I run Sails 1.2.3.

Some attributes are listed here: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes
And validation rules are available here: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations

The problem is that there are some attributes in the models that are not listed in those pages nor anywhere else in the manual (for what I saw.)
An example of this is the 'User' model, which is created by default. 
The attribute 'password' has the 'description' and 'protect' properties for which I haven't found any definition. 
I suppose that there are other properties that I don't know of and are not listed in the previous pages.

Making a search using for "protect" using grep, I did find a file listing all available properties
node_modules/waterline-schema/accessible/valid-attribute-properties.js
The problem is that this is only a list and there are no description of how those attributes work.

I checked on DuckDuckGo and Google to no avail.

My guess is that there is a part of the manual describing properties for more general objects than models and that these properties can be used in the models as well.

I would have expected that this information would be in the manual, but I haven't found it. If I find a resource with these descriptions I intend to make a pull request for Sails manual.

Thank you in advance and have a good day.

Nemo.